# Client-side image cropping and rotating solution using HTML5 <canvas>

Tags: image, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Is there any image cropper based on HTML5 canvas API. What I would like to have is rotating and cropping. Actually I have written one but I did not like it very much.

Answer (score 0):

Pixastic has a [crop feature](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/crop/), does that work for you?

Comment: No, What I want is a more professional library which can utilize another library such as KineticJS or Pixastic. Thx